# Appengine debug TagLibConfiguration (java jetty)

Tags: java, debugging, google-app-engine, jsp, jetty

I'd like to debug the following class in GAE: TagLibConfiguration

To do so I need the exact Jetty Version that GAE uses in order to get the source code and be able to step by step.

Where can I get the source code and the exact Jetty version?

As I deduce by the namespace "org.mortbay.jetty.webapp" it uses a 1.6.* version, isn't it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We know that Google is using some version of jetty 6 but they seem to have basically forked jetty at some point so we (Jetty) have no way of knowing what they have changed from the versions we distribute.

As for getting access to their source code, that will have to come from google somewhere, and then only if it is freely available.  Good luck!  If you do get access somehow please post back here for others.